# If value exists in both array and database

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to check if a value exists in an array, if it does, it should echo the information about that value from the database.

What I get now is "null" results, but I expect to get at least three results in the list, that exists in both array and database.

This is how a var_dump looks of the array, it's not the whole array but it continues to look the same: `$friends = array($friends['data']);`

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(680) {
[0]=>
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(17) "One friends name"
  ["id"]=>
  string(8) "FRIEND_ID"
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(13) "Another friends name"
  ["id"]=>
  string(9) "FRIEND_ID"
}
[2]=>
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(22) "Another friends name"
  ["id"]=>
  string(9) "FRIEND_ID"
}
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php

$query_top_list_friends = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM ".$DBprefix."users 
WHERE center_id='" . $personal['center_id'] . "' 
ORDER BY workouts DESC LIMIT 10");

$i = 0;
$friends = array($friends['data']);

while ($top_list_friends = mysql_fetch_array($query_top_list_friends)) 
{
//Below it should only echo if the "fid" in the database and the "id" in the array is equal, then it should echo information based on that id from the database
if($friends[$top_list_friends['fid']])
{
    $i++;
    echo "<div class='user'>";
    echo "<span class='number'>" . $i . "</span>";
    echo "<span class='name'>" . $top_list_friends['name'] . "</span>";
    echo "<span class='workouts'>" . $top_list_friends['workouts'] . "</span>";
    echo "</div>";
} 
}
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using `SQL`'s `IN`:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Harry'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 8,
        'name' => 'Josh'
    )
);

// create an array with just your fid's
$sql_in_values = array_map(function($ele){
    return $ele['id'];
}, $array);

// select all entries where the fid's are specified
$query_top_list_friends = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM ".$DBprefix."users 
    WHERE center_id='" . $personal['center_id'] . "'
    AND WHERE fid IN ('" . implode(',', $sql_in_values) . "')
    ORDER BY workouts DESC LIMIT 10");

$i = 0;
while($top_list_friends = mysql_fetch_array($query_top_list_friends)){
    echo "<div class='user'>";
    echo "<span class='number'>" . ++$i . "</span>";
    echo "<span class='name'>" . $top_list_friends['name'] . "</span>";
    echo "<span class='workouts'>" . $top_list_friends['workouts'] . "</span>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It almost works great :) But here the variable $query_top_list_friends is empty, do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: If I make a var_dump of $sql_in_values it shows me an array of all id's including the id's that also exists in the database

Comment: Well I was just guessing with the query, try `echo "
    SELECT * FROM ".$DBprefix."users 
    WHERE center_id='" . $personal['center_id'] . "'
    AND WHERE fid IN ('" . implode(',', $sql_in_values) . "')
    ORDER BY workouts DESC LIMIT 10"` and then run the query in PHPMyAdmin (or whatever you use). I used `fid` but maybe that's the wrong `id`?

Comment: Okey, well it looks like the query is okey, and yes `fid` is the name of the id in the db

Comment: Thanks for you help! I managed to do it with adding ' around the id's like this WHERE fid IN ('" . implode('\',\'', $friend_ids) . "')

Comment: @Kim, that must mean you have them in there as chars/varchars. You should change the type of the column to int (your dbms will love for for it).

Comment: Yeah, I did so aswell! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like `$friends = array($friends['data']);` is holding the array of friends at index 0, so when you call `if($friends[$top_list_friends['fid']])` you aren't looking inside the array that holds the friends, but the array of the array that holds the friends, if that makes sense

Try changing `$friends = array($friends['data']);` to `$friends = $friends['data'];` and you should start to get results, but how does fid work? Does it point to the index of the array or a key for the array? See from that array you've posted above the only accessible values are:

```
$friends[0][0] // One friend
$friends[0][1] // Another friend
$friends[0][2] // Another friend
```

So make sure that fid is an integer as calling `$friends[0][$fid]` will need to be an integer 0 to 2 to return any data

Hope that helps and any questions I will be happy to answer

Comment: When you build the $friends array you need to assign the friend data to the FID key `$friends[FID]` so if `$top_list_friends['fid'] = 4` then: `$friends[4] = array(['name'] => "Name", [id] => 4);` So when you call `if($friends[$top_list_friends['fid'])` you are accessing `$friends[4]`